# Replace images in a webpage using se webdriver

Tags: java, selenium

I want to replace certain images in my webpage.
The code i am using to find the images are:

```
 List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@jsname='pCbVjb']//button[@jsname='WR0adb']//img[contains(@srcset, 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com')]"));
int size=elements.size();
```

Now i am trying to replace the images by JavaScriptExecutor

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('srcset' , 'image to be replaced URL')",elements.get(0));
```

So I am reading the data from excel sheet for **image to be replaced URL**
But i am not able to replace the image .

So what  argument i need to pass in **image to be replaced URL** which is coming from sheet?

If I am hardcoding the same its working for me fine but i want to make it dynamic.

Please help me out on this.

Comment: Why are you replacing the URL of images on the page? You realize this isn't permanent, right? As soon as you refresh the page, everything goes back to the way it was and no one else that visits the page will see this.

Answer (score 0):

There's not enough details to give you proper solution, but this is what I think can bring you to one.

1. You have 2 dynamic elements: element itself and the link, so you need to pass 2 arguments into your script: the element, and value you want to inject
2. You need a loop instead of `elements.get(0)`

So generally script would look like this:

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(...));
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

for( WebElement element : elements ) {
   // get next image, not sure how you do it;
   String nextImage = getNextImageToBeReplacedURL();
   js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('srcset' , arguments[1])", element, nextImage );
}
```

where `getNextImageToBeReplacedURL` returns dynamic value coming from Excel.